# store pandas df as blob in oracle database

Tags: python, blob

I want to detect different dataframes in the excel file and give each detected dataframe an id and store this dataframe as an object/blob into Oracle database.

So in DB table, it would look like:

| DF_ID | DF_BLOB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | /*blob string for df 1*/ |
| 2 | /*blob string for df 2*/ |

I know how to store entire excel file as blob in oracle (basically directly store excelfile.read())

but I cannot directly read() or open() pandas df. Then how can I store this df object as blob?

Answer (score 2):

The go to library for storing Python objects in a binary format is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

To get a byte-string instead of writing to a file use `pickle.dumps()`:

> pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True, buffer_callback=None)
> Return the pickled representation of the object obj as a bytes object, instead of writing it to a file.
>
> Arguments protocol, fix_imports and buffer_callback have the same meaning as in the Pickler constructor.

Comment: Thank you! when I use df.to_pickle(), it seems that I must provide a path to store it. Is it possible I can store df.to_pickle() as a variable, so that I can directly use this variable into my sql query later to store the data into db?